# Как получить данные из SQlite по id?

Tags: java, android

Есть база данных SQLITE. Элементы базы данных выводятся в `ListView`.

Моя задача: в `onItemClick` перейти в другой активити, где выводятся все данные нажатого элемента `ListView`. Для этого передаю в новый активити через `intent.putextra` *ID* элемента.

Подскажите, как получить данные из базы данных с помощью *ID*?

```
package com.example.maxim.sqlite;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Kontakt extends AppCompatActivity {
long DIFFICULTY_EASY;
TextView konname;
TextView konphone;
long userId;
SQLiteDatabase db;
String name;
int phone;
DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kontakt);
    //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
    userId = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", DIFFICULTY_EASY);
    Log.d("my","лог "+userId);

    konname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.konname);
    konphone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.konphone);
    sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = "_id = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(userId)};
    Cursor c = db.query("kontakts", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        name  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("COLUMN_NAME"));
        phone = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("COLUMN_PHONE"));
    }
    Log.d("my","лог "+name+phone);

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать метод `query` или `rawQuery`. Ниже пример с использованием метода `query`.

Для этого сформируем параметры для него: название таблицы, а не имя БД как у вас в коде, массив столбцов для выгрузки, если нужны все то передаем `null`, условие по которому будет производится выборка, без ключевого слова `WHERE`, и, так как мы хотим избежать инъекций, параметры для условия отдельным массивом. Остальные параметры устанавливаем `null`, так как нам не важна сортировка, упорядочивание и т.д. Итого получается такой код:

```
String selection = "_id = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
Cursor c = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    // достаем данные из курсора
}
```

Кстати хочу обратить внимание на то, что не надо делать два последовательных вызова методов `moveToFirst()` и `moveToNext()`, т.к. в этом случае будет пропущен первый элемент. Достаточно одного из них в зависимости от того, чего вы хотите - достать первый элемент, или пройтись по всему курсору.

Comment: Похоже что я где-то совершил ошибку,вылетает,обновил код выше.

Comment: @maxim лог ошибки приложите. Судя по обновленному коду вы ошиблись в определении ```selection```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lt5BNqqs

Comment: @maxim Перед использованием объекта ```db``` его сначала надо инициализировать, а так он у вас вылетаем с NPE.

Comment: обновил код, что нужно вставить в selection?

Comment: @maxim то, что у меня в коде

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Bahdk8VT  ругается на name  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("COLUMN_NAME"));

Comment: @maxim ваши ошибки достаточно банальны, попробуйте сначала сами их решить