# Получение данных _id из базы данных SQLite

Tags: android, база-данных

Читаю базу данных, вывожу необходимые данные в ListView
Хочу отработать нажатие на полученный результат и отправить во вторую активность их _id в базе данных

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {                
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SearchActivity.this, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("head", _id);
                //запускаем вторую активность
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Вопрос: как подтянуть из БД этот самый _id?

Вот весь класс:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    ListView userList;
    EditText userFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ppvsList);
        userFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ppvsFilter);

        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        // создаем базу данных
        sqlHelper.create_db();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            db = sqlHelper.open();
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

            // если в текстовом поле есть текст, выполняем фильтрацию
            // данная проверка нужна при переходе от одной ориентации экрана к другой
            if(!userFilter.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                userAdapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());

            // установка слушателя изменения текста
            userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    userAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });

            // устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
            userAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE +
                                        " where " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?" +
                                        " or " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER + " like ?",
                                new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%", "%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                    }
                }
            });

            userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        catch (SQLException ex){}

        // Получим идентификатор ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ppvsList);
        //Обрабатываем щелчки на элементах ListView:
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SearchActivity.this, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("head", id);
                //запускаем вторую активность
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        userCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете позицию адаптера, загляните в адаптер и прочитайте данные которые находятся в позиции.

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, код? Пробую как написано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472980/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-sqlite-%d0%bf%d0%be-id и не получается...

Comment: Покажите класс адаптера и модельку которую передаете в адаптер

Comment: Скинул в топик код всей активности

Comment: Товарищи советовали использовать `int position`, но это позиция в списке после поиска, а она не совпадает с позицией в БД, в связи с чем значение не то, что нужно. Еще есть `long id`, но я не понимаю что это, потому что вторая активность это значение не подхватывает, а берет дефолтное `0`, которое есть на случай, если значение из `intent.putExtra` по какой-то причине не передалось.

Comment: `long id` - это как раз то что нужно, `SimpleCursorAdapter` отдаёт в этот параметр значение из колонки `"_id"`, если она есть в курсоре. Может вы во второй активности его получаете неправильно или нет такой колонки в таблице?

Comment: Странно, это первая колонка в таблице, в ней значения, как и нужно в числах от 0 до 42 (по числу строк)... Может, проблема в том, что ячейки с цифрами записаны как текст (на скриншоте видно)? Но с другой стороны, там только текст, двоичные данные, изображение и XML.... (https://yadi.sk/i/-ntXmw6HboQceg). Во второй активности я его получаю через `String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);`

Comment: `intent.getLongExtra("head", 0);`  - если вы передали `long`, то забирать нужно его же.

Comment: Не понял, что имеете ввиду? Если передаю `position`, то все с таким кодом отлично работает.. Только не с теми данными, что мне нужно

Comment: Я же написал - если вы передаёте `long id`, то получать нужно get**Long**Extra

Comment: Аллилуя!!! Я, чукча невнимательный, этот момент упустил!!